# How can I echo/print the environment files of a directory/path in a Jenkinsfile during a build?

Tags: bash, path, jenkins

In a Jenkins file, I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
....
def env_prod = 'prod.env'
def entrypoint = "${env.WORKSPACE}
```

The above is then combined like this:

```
${env.WORKSPACE}/$env_prod
```

And it is fed into a python script (through `argparse`); the Python script looks like:

```
def get_package_reference_versions(packages, env_path, env_format):
    with open(env_path) as f:
    deps = f.read()
    ....
```

In my Jenkins logs, I see:

```
    [2024-01-25T13:39:41.780Z]   File "/opt/bmll/miniconda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/something/deployment.py", line 421, in get_package_reference_versions

[2024-01-25T13:39:41.780Z]     with open(env_path) as f:

[2024-01-25T13:39:41.780Z]          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

[2024-01-25T13:39:41.780Z] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ec2-user/jenkins/workspace/pipeline-deployments/js-deployment-cr/prod.env'
```

Now I am trying to figure out what is inside the `js-deployment-cr` directory.

Is there a way to print the environment files inside the `js-deployment-cr` directory?

N.B. I CANNOT MAKE CHANGES IN THE PYTHON SCRIPT, because it sits in a different repository to the bash script. So I need to figure this out in the Jenkins file.

Comment: That sounds more like ksh than bash. In bash, I'd expect you to get a `bash: line 1: ${env.WORKSPACE}: bad substitution`

Comment: Sorry, above is actually from a Jenkins log, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: It's not too late, you can always edit your question to bring clarifications (and that's always welcome). It still doesn't explain how such a bash script could produce such output in your *jenkins logs*.  It's  also not clear  to me what exactly you want  to be printed and how (a  list of file paths? of file names? Or of their contents? How should they be separated?...)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have made things much clearer (I hope!) in the question.

Comment: Are you really asking how to list the contents of a directory? If so, then I think you need more help than just asking that question here. Indeed, if this is a work system you probabl should not have access to perform that task. There are lots of introductory Linux and Unix courses free on the internet.

Comment: Sorry it's not contents of a directory, it is environment files inside what (I think) is a path/directory. If it was a straightforward directory that would not be an issue.

Comment: Have you tried listing the contents of the `js-deployment-cr` using `ls`? And what would the contents of a directory be other than a file?

Comment: As @doneal24 suggests, maybe adding

     "ls ${env.WORKSPACE}".execute()

complete with double quotes and period to the groovy will give a listing, assuming that jenkins is running in a unix-like environment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @icarus, unfortunately I run into: `Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods execute java.lang.String`. 

Any other suggestions to get around this?

Comment: Maybe `println(new File("${env.WORKSPACE}").listFiles())` ?

Comment: Maybe `sh("ls ${env.WORKSPACE}")` ?

Comment: Thanks @icarus, I'll try both